# ERROR: Network Error: Connection refused - connect(2).Check your knife configuration and network settings

Tags: chef-infra, devops

While bootstrap a node on hosted chef server i am getting following error

```
$ knife bootstrap xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --ssh-user shivam --ssh-password '******' --sudo --use-sudo-password --node-name chefNode1 --run-list 'recipe[learn_chef_httpd1]'

Creating new client for chefNode2
Creating new node for chefNode2
Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

**ERROR: Network Error: Connection refused - connect(2) for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22
Check your knife configuration and network settings**
```

My knife.rb is

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

log_level                :info

log_location             STDOUT

node_name                "gshivam63"

client_key               "#{current_dir}/gshivam63.pem"

chef_server_url          "https://api.chef.io/organizations/gshivam63_chef"

cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```

Comment: Is the node you trying to bootstrap a local vm? Check network settings of vm. Try with nat

Comment: Yes it is local vm, i tried with public address also

dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com

This gives ipaddress: 157.49.109.38

But getting same error

Network Settings in VM are
Ipv4:192.168.108.129

Ipv6:fe80::cd2:f00c:d3ec:2a22

Default Route:192.168.108.2

DNS:192.168.108.2

Answer (score 0):

This means `knife` was not able to open an SSH connection to the target you specified. Unfortunately the number of reasons this can fail are far too numerous to go over here, but check that you can SSH into the target host manually and if you can't, look for the usual network errors like a bad firewall, incorrect routing config, and check that sshd itself is actually running.

Answer (score 0):

I have run following commands on vm local workstation, vm local node and local pc and problem got resolved

sudo apt update

sudo apt install ssh

sudo ufw allow 22

sudo chmod -R 777 /etc